# How to automatically detect the arguments to pass in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

So here's one example. I have a module with multiple classes for computing properties, let's say, Density. Then, I have substances, whom I make inherit the properties, so I can call them afterwards:

```
class Density():

    def __init__(self):
        self.rho_method_1_A = None
        self.rho_method_1_B = None
        self.rho_method_2_A = None
        self.rho_method_2_B = None

   def density_method_1(self,T):
        return self.rho_method_1_A*T + self.rho_method_1_B*T**2

   def density_method_2(self,T,P):
        return P*(self.rho_method_2_A/T + self.rho_method_1_B*log(T))

class Water(Density):
       
   def __init__(self):
        self.rho_method_1_A = 0.2
        self.rho_method_1_B = 0.0088
        self.rho_method_2_A = 1.9
        self.rho_method_2_B = 10

Water.density_method_1(T=300)
```

Basically, I want the user to be able to set beforehand the method of choice. The problem is, depending on the model that he/she chose, it will either accept only T, or both T and P (in some other cases, maybe T won't even be accepted). Essentially:

```
 density_method = density_method_2 # This is chosen by the user in an outer module
 Water.density_method(code magically knows what to put here by detecting the arguments that 
                      density_method_2 accepts)
```

To be clear: The user itself will know which arguments the method accepts, so if he chose method_2, P will be known on the outer module. I suspect **kwargs and/or decorators are part of the solution, but I can't quite figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks and have a great weekend.

Update: It is relevant to notice that density_method will be called inside a temporal loop of tens of thousands of iterations. So, I'm trying to avoid if/else statements by completely defining density_method before starting the temporal loop.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution (tested with Python 3.8):

```
from math import log


class Density():
  def __init__(self, method=1):
      self.method = method
      self.rho_method_1_A = None
      self.rho_method_1_B = None
      self.rho_method_2_A = None
      self.rho_method_2_B = None

  def density_method_1(self, T):
    return self.rho_method_1_A*T + self.rho_method_1_B*T**2

  def density_method_2(self, T, P):
    return P*(self.rho_method_2_A/T + self.rho_method_1_B*log(T))

  def density_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.method == 1:
      return self.density_method_1(*args, **kwargs)
    elif self.method == 2:
      return self.density_method_2(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
      raise ValueError("No density method found")


class Water(Density):      
  def __init__(self, method):
    super(Water, self).__init__(method=method)
    self.rho_method_1_A = 0.2
    self.rho_method_1_B = 0.0088
    self.rho_method_2_A = 1.9
    self.rho_method_2_B = 10


class Air(Density):      
  def __init__(self, method):
    super(Air, self).__init__(method=method)
    self.rho_method_1_A = 0.2
    self.rho_method_1_B = 0.0088
    self.rho_method_2_A = 1.9
    self.rho_method_2_B = 10


water = Water(method=1)
air = Air(method=2)

print(water.density_method(T=1))
print(air.density_method(T=1, P=2))
```

The solution can be improved but the general idea is to have a "wrapper" method `density_method` that calls the relevant `density_method_*` for each sub-class of `Density`.

**Edit (following the comments to my answer):**

You should look into python method overloading, like the example here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-method-overloading/

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch 
  
#passing one parameter 
@dispatch(int,int) 
def product(first,second): 
    result = first*second 
    print(result); 
  
#passing two parameters 
@dispatch(int,int,int) 
def product(first,second,third): 
    result  = first * second * third 
    print(result); 
  
#you can also pass data type of any value as per requirement 
@dispatch(float,float,float) 
def product(first,second,third): 
    result  = first * second * third 
    print(result); 
  
  
#calling product method with 2 arguments 
product(2,3,2) #this will give output of 12 
product(2.2,3.4,2.3) # this will give output of 17.985999999999997
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention and input. As you can tell, I used dummy values and equations to represent the idea. I will try and test this right now and return to you if this idea works.

Comment: A problem to my application that I can see right out the gates, is that I will call density_method inside a temporal loop (tens of thousands of iterations). So my idea was to completely define density_method outside the temporal loop and avoid if/else statements. Is there any way to do this? I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: See my edit, python method overloading can be helpful if you want to avoid many if-else statements.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! However, this still does not completely solve my problem; If I understand correctly, this multiple dispatcher can only resolve the types of the variables (not a keyword for example), so if I happen to have 2 different implementations of "Density" with the same number of parameters, all floats, there would be ambiguity e.g.: method_1(T,P) and method_2(T,mu). Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try to use `*args, **kwargs` as a workaround: https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/ (check if `T, P` or `T, mu` are in **kwargs and choose the method accordingly).

Comment: I think I managed to implement this solution yesterday. I'm still developing the code a little bit to confirm it is really useful, and then I'll post the specific solution that worked. Thanks for your input, again!

Comment: Happy to help and I also think that the question itself is interesting.